# Upload file from @ondrop event as ByteArray

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I am trying to have a div where I can drag and drop a file onto. This file should be uploaded to my backend as a ByteArray and stored in a blob storage.

I already have this implementation of uploading a file to my backend:

```cs
private byte[] content;

private async Task HandleFileUpload(IBrowserFile file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.OpenReadStream(50000000).CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            content = memoryStream.ToArray();

            TixoFilesDTO tixoFilesDto = new TixoFilesDTO()
                {
                    Content = content,
                    Name = file.Name,
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                    TicketId = TicketId,
                };

            var result = await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(TixoApiRoutes.TixoFiles.POST_File(), tixoFilesDto);

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                await LoadFiles();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am struggling to get the file from the @ondrop event to a IBrowserFile.

```cs
private async Task OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    var fileList = e.DataTransfer.Items;

    foreach (var file in fileList)
    {
        await HandleFileUpload(file);
    }
}
```

This is how I implemented the @ondrop event:

```
<div id="dropZone" @ondrop="OnDrop" @ondrop:preventDefault="true" @ondrop:stopPropagation="true" ondragover="event.preventDefault()">
    Drop file here
</div>
```

Comment: You don't want a `Byte[]` - you want a `Stream`.